# Python Object Oriented

Tags: python, oop, object, parameters, self

I was kinda playing around with Object Oriented Programming in python and ran into an error i havent encountered before..:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, a , b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def even(self):
        start = self.a
        slut = self.b
        while start <= slut:
            if start % 2 == 0:
                yield start
            start += 1

    def odd(self):
        start = self.a
        slut = self.b
        while start <= slut:
            if start % 2 != 0:
                yield start
            start += 1

    def display():
        evens = list(num.even())
        odds = list(num.odd())
        print(f"{evens}'\n'{odds}")

num = Main(20, 50)

Main.display()
```

---

Take a look at the last class method, where there shouldent be a 'self' as a parameter for the program to Work..Why is that? I thought every class method should include a 'self' as a parameter? The program wont work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `self` parameter, if it's intended to be an instance method, and you would get an error if you tried to use it as so, i.e., `num.display()`.

However, you are calling it via the *class*, and `Main.display` simply returns the function itself, not an instance of `method`, so it works as-is.

Given that you use a *specific* instance of `Main` (namely, `num`) in the body, you should replace that with `self`:

```
def display(self):
    evens = list(self.even())
    odds = list(self.odd())
    print(f"{evens}'\n'{odds}")
```

and invoke it with

```
num.display()
```